# Finding source of unidentified node name for celery worker (seen in DuplicateNodenameWarning when trying flower)

Tags: celery, django-celery, flower

For a Django project running celery tasks, I'm running celery flower with the command: `python manage.py celery flower --address=0.0.0.0 --port=5555`

The server starts correctly, but I get the warning:

```
[W 161223 17:18:02 control:36] /home/myuser/myenv/myproj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/control.py:36: DuplicateNodenameWarning: Received multiple replies from node name: 'names'.
```

Look at the very end of that warning. It says my node is named `names`. I don't get it. I'm running celery tasks via supervisor, and none of the nodes there are named `names`.

What's going on? How do I diagnose this problem? I'm essentially trying to solve this warning message and have it go away.

p.s. no mention of it in `/etc/default/celeryd` either

---

Here's `supervisord.conf`:

```
; supervisor config file

[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)
environment=ON_AZURE="1"

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or
; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
; include files themselves.

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

`celery.conf` is:

```
[program:celeryworker1]
command=python manage.py celery worker -l info -n celeryworker1
directory = /home/myuser/myproject
environment=PATH="/home/myuser/myenvs/projenv/bin",VIRTUAL_ENV="/home/myuser/myenvs/projenv",PYTHONPATH="/home/myuser/myenvs/projenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
user=myuser
password=mypassword
process_name=%(program_name)s%(process_num)d@%(host_node_name)s
numprocs=4
stdout_logfile = /etc/supervisor/logs/celery-worker.log
stderr_logfile = /etc/supervisor/logs/celery-worker.log
autostart = true
autorestart = true
startsecs=10

stopwaitsecs = 600

killasgroup = true

priority = 998
```

Comment: Do you have multiple Q? 
Please provide the configuration of supervisor.

Comment: As in, `supervisor.conf`?

Comment: yes, please provide if you still haven't solve your issue

Comment: @Jinje: provided. The issue is still pending.

Comment: How about celery supervisor conf?

Comment: @Jinje: put that in as well. Check it out.

Comment: i try to run almost same settings, the only different you are running `python manage.py celery`(management command), i'm running `celery -A project_name flower --address=0.0.0.0 --port=5555`.

Comment: Surprisingly it works in `localhost`, but in production, I still get `[W 170104 18:08:21 control:36] /home/myuser/myenvs/projenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/control.py:36: DuplicateNodenameWarning: Received multiple replies from node name: 'name'.
    Please make sure you give each node a unique nodename using the '-n' option.
      pluralize(len(dupes), 'name'), ', '.join(sorted(dupes)),`. The exact command I ran was `python manage.py celery -A myproject flower --address:<server IP> --port:5555 -l info`.

Comment: Ur issue should be the `numprocs=4`, try to set it to 1.

Set the number of worker by using `--concurrency=4`